# Do thread pools incur context switch overhead?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

When a thread switches between tasks that have been submitted to a thread pool, does it incur a context switch overhead(or something similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Context switch is a process of storing and restoring state of a thread. This is important when you have more threads then your CPU supports. So that your OS can emulate many threads over small number of physical threads. Simply speaking `more threads == more overhead` because context switch has to occure more often (so that we still have ilusion of things happening parallely). Up to a point when it crashes your system. :)

However when a thread switches between tasks then these tasks have to be stored somewhere. This is usually done by a queue. So from thread's point of view this is simply `queue.pop()` and continue processing.

Now no matter what the implementation of the queue is there has to be a consistency and atomicity guarantee of `.pop()` operation. Such a guarantee always comes with a small (or big, implementation dependent) overhead.

So yes, switching between tasks comes with a performance hit, but this has nothing to do with context switch.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. So if I set up a thread pool of size 50, and there are only 4 physical threads available, there will still be some context switching between the 50 right?

Comment: @frodo Yes, definitely. But you should be fine with `50`, it's a small number, the overhead should be small.

Comment: Okay cool. I guess I am looking for a guideline on how to choose the size of a threadpool.

Comment: @frodo That's a tricky question. You won't get an answer like "use 100 threads". This depends on your machine, on other processes, etc. What you should do is to try different scenarios and see how it performs.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. Thanks!